# Unable to generate a URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am currently trying to create a link on the index page that'll allow users to create an item. My routes.php looks like

```
Route::controller('items', 'ItemController');
```

and my ItemController looks like

```
class ItemController extends BaseController
{
  // create variable
  protected $item;

  // create constructor
  public function __construct(Item $item)
  {
    $this->item = $item;
  }

  public function getIndex()
  {
    // return all the items
    $items = $this->item->all();

    return View::make('items.index', compact('items'));
  }

  public function getCreate()
  {
    return View::make('items.create');
  }

  public function postStore()
  {
    $input = Input::all();

    // checks the input with the validator rules from the Item model
    $v = Validator::make($input, Item::$rules);

    if ($v->passes())
    {
      $this->items->create($input);

      return Redirect::route('items.index');
    }

    return Redirect::route('items.create');
  }
}
```

I have tried changing the getIndex() to just index() but then I get a controller method not found. So, that is why I am using getIndex().

I think I have set up my create controllers correctly but when I go to the items/create url I get a

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "items.store" as such route does not exist.

error. I have tried using just store() and getStore() instead of postStore() but I keep getting the same error.

Anybody know what the problem might be? I don't understand why the URL isn't being generated.

Comment: **+1 for posting a _broad code sample_ with your question!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Route::controller() which does generate route names as far as I know.

i.e. you are referring to "items.store" - that is a route name.

You should either;

- Define all routes specifically ([probably best - see this blog here](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil))
- Use `Route::resource('items', 'ItemController');` [see docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers)

If you use Route::resource - then you'll need to change your controller names

Comment: Ohhhh I misread about controller and resource. Okay, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: How does this answer relate to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28388716/3334390) I have, where one file in the same folder loads using the Stylesheets function, but another does not? In my example, it's not necessary to define the routes to stylesheets, that happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you, that the *route name* is not defined:

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "items.store" **as such route does not exist**.

Have a look in the Laravel 4 Docs in the [**Named Routes** section](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes). There are several *examples* that'll make you clear how to use these kind of routes.

Also have a look at the [**RESTful Controllers** section](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers).

***Here's an example for your question:***

```
Route::get('items', array(
    'as'   => 'items.store',
    'uses' => 'ItemController@getIndex',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

As The Shift Exchange said, Route::controller() doesn't generate names, but you can do it using a third parameter:

```
Route::controller(  'items', 
                    'ItemController', 
                    [
                        'getIndex' => 'items.index',
                        'getCreate' => 'items.create',
                        'postStore' => 'items.store',
                        ...
                    ]
);
```