# Symfony Unable to Generate a URL for Route to Stylesheet

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have two CSS files in the same folder, with identical access rights. When testing in the same Twig file, one CSS file generates a URL to the file and loads perfectly and one gives an error.

### Error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_a328b4c_0" as
>   such route does not exist.") in @GutensiteStream/Stream35163.html.twig
>   at line 19.

### Files on Server

```
ls -al /var/www/core/cms/src/Templates/GutensiteAdminBundle/Resources/public/css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chadwick developer  17K Feb  7 14:00 dashboard.css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chadwick developer  49K Feb  6 16:00 site.css
```

### Template with CSS that Loads

```
{% stylesheets '@TemplatesGutensiteAdminBundle/Resources/public/css/site.css' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

### Template with CSS that does NOT Load

```
{% stylesheets '@TemplatesGutensiteAdminBundle/Resources/public/css/dashboard.css' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

### Linking to the File Directly Works

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/gutensite/v/2/0/bundles/templatesgutensiteadmin/css/dashboard.css">
```

### Steps Taken

I have already cleared cache multiple times, via `app/console cache:clear` and via `rm -rf app/cache/*`. I use `php app/console assets:install --symlink /var/www/core/web/gutensite/v/2/0/` to symlink the public files to the bundles, and of course they are accessible (as demonstrated via the direct link).

### My Config.yml

```
assetic:
    #don't use dynamic links to assets, use full production paths
    use_controller: false
```

Comment: please try `@TemplatesGutensiteAdminBundle/Resources/public/css/*`

Comment: Well, I don't actually want to load ALL css in that folder. In this case I don't actually want the site.css, that was just to confirm the syntax was correct. I want the dashboard.css

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into this error, the solution was quite simple:

When in doubt:

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

Assetic is looked for a cached version which doesn't exist. This could be for any number of reasons, but `cache:clear` seems like it should be the first stop.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use the @ helper and load css directly from your bundle in production.

The best practice approach is to store the css files in the app/Resources directory and using `assets:install` requesting them from the web root, but seing as you don't have an AppBundle, the second best thing would be to request them from the web/bundles directory:

```
    {% stylesheets
    'bundles/templategutenstideadmin/css/site.css'
    'bundles/templategutenstideadmin/css/dashboard.css'
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

Make sure you run `assets:install` beforehand. 
This way, your css files will be compressed to one file and they will be loaded with the latest changes from the `assets:install` command.

Loading css files directly from your bundle using @ is not recommended outside of local testing. I suspect your first issue is the usage of muliple stylesheets tags in assetic (stylesheets tag is not a part of Twig), but generally using @ for file linking is not a good idea for assets. Use it for things like routing and config in .yml files, but not for assets! :)

Comment: @ is not bad. It's bad to have a project with some bundles and push all css into app/Resources. I do use @Bundle and it works like a charm. In dev I let assetic use the controller, so the URL to css and js is the path to the compiled folder but the resource doesn't exists, so it's dispatched via Symfony. When I switch to production I dump them and they are accessed via Apache without PHP. That's how I want it.

Comment: [Symfony docs say it's okay](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets) to use the @ syntax for CSS, but "there is a known issue that causes the cssrewrite filter to fail when using the @AppBundle syntax for CSS Stylesheets". But either way, what I don't understand is why the first file will load, but if I REPLACE the filename with the second, it doesn't work (only one being requested on each test, not that it should matter).

Comment: Also, why shouldn't the @ syntax be used for assets? The [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) show it being used for javascript, images, and CSS. So what is the logic behind why you recommend against this practice (other than a known bug with rewrite filters in CSS). Also, FYI, I use assets:install with symlinks, so I don't know if that makes a difference with the deployment. I assume it doesn't compress the files together like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

One instance where this error will occur is when you try to load such an asset in a child template, that is already being loaded in one of the parent templates.

To fix it, load the asset only once in a template chain.

(Have to post this as answer, as I can't comment, yet.)

Answer (score 0):

config.yml

```
assetic:
    bundles: [you bundle name , otherbundlename]  #add this
```

Comment: More details please. In my example I was loading two files, from the identical bundle and folder. So please explain why this would be necessary and what it does. Thank you.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.